# BinarySearch not working for reversed array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search, linear-search

I am working on a project for school that tests Binary Search vs. Linear Search. My LinearSearch method seems to work fine when the array is in either increasing order or reversed. However, the BinarySearch **only** works when the array is in increasing order, but fails to work when the array is reversed. I am not sure what is causing this and would appreciate any suggestions/solutions.

Here is my code

```
/*
 * SearchTest.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 16, 2022
 *      Author: JH
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


//BinarySearch method
int BinarySearch(int numbers[], int numbersSize, int key) {
   int mid;
   int low;
   int high;

   low = 0;
   high = numbersSize - 1;

   while (high >= low) {
      mid = (high + low) / 2;
      if (numbers[mid] < key) {
         low = mid + 1;
      }
      else if (numbers[mid] > key) {
         high = mid - 1;
      }
      else {
         return mid;
      }
   }

   return -1; // not found
}


//LinearSearch method
int LinearSearch(int* array, int arraySize, int key) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
      if (array[i] == key) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   return -1; // not found
}


//method to reverse array elements
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}


int main() {
    //declare array
    int reverseArr[1000];
    int size = sizeof(reverseArr)/sizeof(reverseArr[0]);

    //initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        reverseArr[i] = i;
    }

    //reverse array
    reverseArray(reverseArr, 0, size-1);

    //print array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << reverseArr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //generate random number
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNum = rand() % 1000;

    //print statements
    cout << "[Linear vs. Binary Search]" << endl;
    cout << "The target value is " << reverseArr[randomNum] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //call BinarySearch method for array
    cout << "Binary Search Test: " << endl;
    int key1 = reverseArr[randomNum];
    int keyIndex1 = BinarySearch(reverseArr, size, key1);

    if (keyIndex1 == -1) {
        cout << key1 << " was not found." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Found " << key1 << " at index " << keyIndex1 << "." << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    //call LinearSearch method for array
    cout << "Linear Search Test: " << endl;
    int key2 = reverseArr[randomNum];
    int keyIndex2 = LinearSearch(reverseArr, size, key2);

    if (keyIndex2 == -1) {
        cout << key2 << " was not found." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Found " << key2 << " at index ";
        cout << keyIndex2 << "." << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: ypu need to change the binary chop to go to higher index if found value is greater. than searched value. Try it with pencil and papaer

Comment: Well, you can compare first and last value to know if your array is reversed and then take that into account when doing comparisons or when computing indexes. Obviously that only works if the array is sorted (in either direction).

Comment: *"My LinearSearch method seems to work fine when the array is in either increasing order or reversed"* -- this means you can drop your linear search from your question and code. Perhaps keep a mention of it at the *end* of your question, if you feel it is useful to give the background of why you are doing this, but don't clutter your **example** with code that is not needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: *" the BinarySearch **only** works when the array is in increasing order"* -- this is how a traditional binary search behaves. What have you added to your function to allow it to handle either increasing or decreasing input?

Comment: In the interest of keeping your [mre] simple, you could drop your function to reverse the array if you initialized it using `reverseArr[i] = size - i - 1;` instead of `reverseArr[i] = i;` (even if your homework requires this function -- after all, we are not grading your homework).